# How to keep pinned tabs from unpinning when entering debug mode in visual studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a bunch of pinned tabs that I would like to stay pinned. Sometimes, when I enter debug mode, all of my document tabs become unpinned, and I lose all context that what I was currently working on, where I might like to set breakpoints, etc.

This normally happens when I close & open visual studio again, getting the set of tabs from the previous session.

Is there any way to disable this?

Answer (score 4):

This should be the answer, it worked for me:

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Tabs and Windows` and make sure "Maintain pin status if document is removed from well" is checked.

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120643/vs2012-productivity-power-tools-pinned-tabs-close-on-run

I do have the Power Productivity tools extension installed and enabled but the "Maintain pin status if document is removed from well" option is a Visual Studio option, unrelated to Power Productivity Tools as the Power Productivity Tools extensions adds its own section to Visual Studio Options it doesn't alter the core Visual Studio options.

Comment: Interesting, I'm trying this now. I never looked at this because the stated function isn't what I want. But having to unpin before closing would be a small price to pay for losing everything. Will accept if I don't see this happen for a few days...

Comment: Why do they even remove the documents? I'd like it if those documents just stayed where I put them, even during debugging.